Replicating records in Pandas based on some condition and efficiently
I have a pandas data frame with records  like the  below:
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'APPN': [1001, 1002, 1003, 1004, 1005, 1006],
    'Applct_Id_1': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', None, 'F'],
    'Applct_Id_2': [None, 'E', 'F', None, 'G', None],
    'Applct_Id_3': ['W', 'Z', None, 'Y', None],
    'Name': ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Charlie', 'David', 'Eve', 'Frank'],
    'Age': [25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50]
})

Ideally, all values for APPN are  unique. However, there are  different  Applct_Ids like  Applct_Id_1 etc  in each APPN. Like 1001 one has  A (Applct_Id_1) and  W (Applct_Id_3). Applct_Id_2 is None  so not of interest. What I want to do is to replicate the records for in row with 1001 on Applct_Id_1 and  Applct_Id_3. The idea I have is  to create a new column called ID_Number and  record the values for  Applct_Id_1 and Applct_Id_3 for each APPN like 1001 for this example. This  will be  followed by a copy of row affecting  this  APPPN.  I acknowledge  that this  will be  different for other APPN. Therefore, the replication  of  records will only be  for APPNs with more than 1 recorded  Applct_Id in the dataset. At the  end  I want to achieve something like  this  for  1001 as an example.
new_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'APPN': [1001, 1001],
    'ID_Number': ['A', 'W'],   
    'Name': ['Alice', 'Alice'],
    'Age': [25, 25]
})

How  can I do this in an efficient way  in Pandas as I'll be  dealing with about 400K records?

I would suggest melting the dataframe anf then fiter the relevant rows:
import pandas as pd

# Example DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'APPN': [1001, 1002, 1003, 1004, 1005, 1006],
    'Applct_Id_1': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', None, 'F'],
    'Applct_Id_2': [None, 'E', 'F', None, 'G', None],
    'Applct_Id_3': ['W', 'Z', None, 'Y', None, None],
    'Name': ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Charlie', 'David', 'Eve', 'Frank'],
    'Age': [25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50]
})

melted_df = df.melt(id_vars=['APPN', 'Name', 'Age'], value_vars=['Applct_Id_1', 'Applct_Id_2', 'Applct_Id_3'], 
                    var_name='ID_Type', value_name='ID_Number')

melted_df = melted_df[melted_df['ID_Number'].notna()]
melted_df = melted_df.drop(columns=['ID_Type'])
melted_df = melted_df.sort_values(by=['APPN', 'ID_Number'])
print(melted_df)

which gives
   APPN     Name  Age ID_Number
0   1001    Alice   25         A
12  1001    Alice   25         W
1   1002      Bob   30         B
7   1002      Bob   30         E
13  1002      Bob   30         Z
2   1003  Charlie   35         C
8   1003  Charlie   35         F
3   1004    David   40         D
15  1004    David   40         Y
10  1005      Eve   45         G
5   1006    Frank   50         F


Thank you. Melt function worked.
